# How can I use apex AMP (Automatic Mixed Precision) with model parallelism on Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, automatic-mixed-precision

My model has a few LSTMs which run out of Cuda memory when run on large sequences with one GPU. So I shifted a few components of the model to another GPU. I tried 2 things with Apex AMP:

1. Move the model components to another GPU before invoking `amp.initialize`. In this case, I get NaNs soon after first backpropagation.
2. First invoke `amp.initialize`, and then move the model components to another GPU. In this case, its like the model backpropagation runs on a single GPU. It runs out of Cuda memory.

The model training runs fine without Apex, so I suppose I am missing some step where the loss is backpropagated on both GPUs. I looked through the [documentations](https://nvidia.github.io/apex/parallel.html) of Apex, however, it only talks about DataParallelism, and not ModelParallelism.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try [PyTorch's AMP](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html)? It should be straightforward, you don't have to do anything I guess.

Comment: Due to some issues I have to use an older version of Pytorch, which does not contain AMP. So I'm using [NVIDIA Apex](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex)

Comment: If anyone else is looking for an answer, got the response [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-apex-amp-automatic-mixed-precision-with-model-parallelism/94337/2). It may not be possible to do it with Apex.